# JSlider throwing illegalArgument exception:invalid range properties

Tags: java, swing, illegalargumentexception, jslider

I have a simple panel with a JSlider and 3 jtextfields.
I am constructing a JSlider using the constructor JSlider(int min, int max, int value)
like this :

```
public class Slide extends JFrame{

    JSlider slider=new JSlider(100,200,50);//here lies the problem
    JTextField maxVal=new JTextField(10);
    JTextField minVal=new JTextField(10);
    JTextField curVal=new JTextField(10);
    public Slide(){


        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
                minVal.setText(slider.getMinimum()+"");
                maxVal.setText(slider.getMaximum()+"");
                curVal.setText(slider.getValue()+"");

            }
        });
        panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[][][][]", "[][][][]"));



        panel.add(slider, "cell 0 0,alignx left,aligny top");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Min val");
        panel.add(label,"cell 0 2");
        panel.add(minVal, "cell 3 2");
        this.setContentPane(panel);
        JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("Max val:");
        panel.add(maxVal,"cell 3 3");
        panel.add(label_1, "cell 0 3");
        panel.add(new JLabel("Cur value:"), "cell 0 4");
        panel.add((curVal),"cell 3 4");
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Slide();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to run this program I get an illegal argument exception but if i remove the third argument everything is ok.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid range properties
    at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.<init>(DefaultBoundedRangeModel.java:102)
    at javax.swing.JSlider.<init>(JSlider.java:274)
    at javax.swing.JSlider.<init>(JSlider.java:241)
    at JSlider.Slide.<init>(Slide.java:20)
    at JSlider.Slide.main(Slide.java:54)
Java Result: 1
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: API talks about constructor [JSlider(int min, int max, int value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html), then minimal value is declared as 100, max is about 200, initial value must equals or to be grather than 100, but is at 50

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Java Documentation:

[JSlider(int min, int max, int value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html#JSlider%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

Creates a horizontal slider using the specified min, max and value.

The BoundedRangeModel that holds the slider's data handles any issues that may arise from improperly setting the minimum, initial, and maximum values on the slider. See the **[BoundedRangeModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoundedRangeModel.html)** documentation for details.

[BoundedRangeModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoundedRangeModel.html)

```
minimum <= value <= value+extent <= maximum
```

The parameters should hold the above relationship. In your case 100 (`min`) is more than 50 (`value`).